# epsilon-delta finding a relationship for $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

So I have the following problem:

$\lim_{x\to -1}$ $\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}$ $=\frac{-1}{2}$

From using the defintion $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

I got

$$\frac{|1+x|}{2|x-1|}$$

I have control over $|x-a|<\delta$

Which in my case is $|x-(-1)|<\delta$

i.e   $$|x+1|<\delta$$

Since I don't have any control over $\frac{1}{2|x-1|}$

I assumed that $\delta \le 1$

Following the procedure for finding the interval for $\frac{1}{2|x-1|}$

I got $$-6<2(x-1)<-2$$

from

$$|x+1|<\delta$$

Now using what I know from $$\frac{|1+x|}{2|x-1|} <\epsilon$$

together with

$$|x-(-1)|<\delta$$

Which got me $$|x+1|<-2\epsilon$$

hence

$$\delta=-2\epsilon$$

Which apperently is wrong, it should've beeen $\delta=2\epsilon$ instead.

What am I doing wrong in my calculations?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gotten

$$-6 < 2(x-1) < -2$$

Since absolute value is a decreasing function when the domain is the set of negative numbers, this implies that

$$2 < 2|x-1| < 6$$

$$1< |x-1| < 3$$

$$\frac13<\frac{1}{|x-1|}<1$$

$$\frac{|1+x|}{2|x-1|}<\frac{\delta}{2}$$

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!